# how to add address of visual c++ 2015 in environment variable windows?

Tags: installation, visual-c++-2015

I installed visual c++ 2015 on Windows 7. I encountered the following error:

```
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 
14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

please guide me

Comment: If you installed it correctly, it should have installed a shortcut to a "Developer Command Prompt" (or similar) which opens a command prompt window with all the correct settings to and paths set up to run the compiler and other tools. If you need the location for some other use, then either use the command prompt to query environment variables and the path to find out, or just search the disk.

Comment: I need the location for some other use. what do i do exactly? I edited question

Comment: thank you. I find that location. I then encountered the error shown above. can you help me?

Comment: Now your question is ***very*** different from what it originally was. Please don't drastically change your questions. If you have a new question post it as a new question.